# How to config my Heroku app to restrict the access to it's herokuapp.com domain a specific server?

Tags: nginx, heroku, devops, server-side-rendering

I have 2 heroku apps, one for API server and one for Node.js server. I would like to allow the Node.js server to access `api-server.herokuapp.com` when doing server-side rendering (since it's faster to access the api server via internal router rather than access it via a custom domain, which needs to pass requests through external DNS).
However, I would also want to restrict the access to `api-server.herokuapp.com` to the Node.js server. That is, browsers can not access `api-server.herokuapp.com`. Browsers can only access the api server via the custom api domain. If someone try to access `api-server.herokuapp.com` directly, the request will be redirect to the custom api domain.
My question is - How can I tell if the request come from my Node.js heroku server but not other agents? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have an Nginx outside Heroku or are you using the default heroku load balancer?

Comment: @JRichardsz I use Nginx inside my Heroku app (it's a buildpack).

Answer (score 1):

You could try these approaches:

## At Linux level

```
iptables -A block_outgoing -j DROP -d blah.com
iptables -A block_outgoing -j DROP -d ww1.blah.com
iptables -A block_outgoing -j DROP -d ww2.blah.com
iptables -A block_outgoing -j DROP -d ww3.blah.com
```

Reference : https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-iptables-6-how-to-block-outgoing-access-to-selectedspecific-ip-address.html

---

## At load balancer level (Linux with full control)

If you have a nginx with **full control** in front of your **internal** apps:

[image: basic nginx diagram]

**Disable api.domain.com public access.**

There is no need to **restrict** the access to **api.domain.com** because they are **internal** without public ip. This internal apps can only be consumed from within your LAN network.

**Only specific app is allowed consume another app**

- You could use nginx Block And Deny IP Address

```
  allow 10.10.100.20; # Allow a single remote host
  deny all; # Deny everyone else
```

Reference: https://support.hypernode.com/knowledgebase/blocking-allowing-ip-addresses-in-nginx/

- CORS

Also you can use **Access-Control-Allow-Origin**

Reference :

- https://gist.github.com/Stanback/7145487
- https://serverfault.com/a/829402/490115

  ### - https://qa.lsproc.com/post/access-control-allow-origin-multiple-origin-domains

## At load balancer level (nginx on heroku)

If you are using nginx as a heroku app and/or you have full control, you could replicate the previous configuration

**Note:** As far as i know :

- Heroku does not give you an internal ip, only the public domain : *.herokuapp.com
- You don't have a full linux control in Heroku

---

## At node.js source code

At this level, you could use:

- CORS

```
app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://domain1.com,http://domain2.com");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
  next();
});
```

Reference:
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/9429405/3957754

- Host Header

This header value is the host from which the request was made:

```
var host = req.headers['host'];
```

So, you just need to implement a custom logic to show an error or redirect for specific hosts.